# Tailwind classes space-x or space-y not working in IE 11

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss

I am using tailwind version 1.4.6 in one of my projects and have found that using the classes space-x and space-y are not working in IE 11.

I have read through the docs and have found to install postcss-custom-properties to help support some of their features for IE 11. I have done this and have included it within my plugins (below is a snippet of what plugins which are imported)

Tailwind mentioned here for IE support
https://v1.tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#variables

```
plugins: [
    require("@tailwindcss/custom-forms"),
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('postcss-custom-properties'),
]
```

Is there something I am missing as to why this isnt working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly set the target in your tailwind config file to `ie11`. The default target is `relaxed`. It seems like a good idea to selectively target `ie11` for the space plugin, reading through comments on this [PR](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/1635).

**Add this** to your `tailwind.config.js`:

```
{
  target: [
    'relaxed',
    {
      space: 'ie11'
    }
  ]
}
```

The space utility plugin uses local css variables when the default `relaxed` target is set, which is not supported in IE11 and [postcss-custom-properties](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-properties) (only applies to css variables defined in the `:root` selector):

[image: Demonstrating css styles applied to space utility class]

This local variable implementation will be replaced when targeting `ie11`. As such, keep in mind that `space-x-reverse` and `space-y-reverse` utilities **will not work**.